# Using a certain theorem to calculate the number of stacks cards with the same color.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider the following theorem:

> Let $A$ be a set of size $n$. Then there are
>   $\frac{n!}{k_{1}!\cdot\ldots\cdot k_{t}!}$ ways to partition this set
>   into $t$ nonempty set of sizes $k_{i}$.

And consider the following example:

> There are $36$ cards, with half of them being blue and half being
>   black. These cards are shuffled and then divided into two equal stacks
>   of $18$ cards. One has to determine the probability that in both
>   stacks there is the same number of blue and black cards.

My question is: How can this example by solved *with the above theorem*
?

The answer is $\frac{\binom{18}{9}\binom{18}{9}}{\binom{36}{18}}$ - but I got to it with
 my own solution which doesn't use the above theorem, which bothers me, since in
the notes I'm reading, this example comes as a *direct application* of
the above theorem.

---

For anyone who cares, heres my solution: If the number
of blue and black cards has to be identical in both stacks, we have
to have $9$ blue and $9$ black cards in both decks. Since there
are $18$ blue and $18$ black cards totally, there are $\binom{18}{9}\binom{18}{9}$
possibilities for one stack. But if we select one stack, the other
is automatically determined, so there are actually $\binom{18}{9}\binom{18}{9}$
possibilities to select both stacks. Since totally there are $\binom{36}{18}$ ways
to divide the cards into arbitrary stacks of the same size, we get the answer).

Comment: Your solution is better. And the formula you were given counts *ordered* partitions, not partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the numerator, from the theorem there are $\frac{18!}{9!\cdot 9!}$ ways to partition the $18$ blue cards into two (ordered, as André Nicolas commented) sets of $9$ blue cards and $9$ blue cards, and similarly for the black cards.

For the denominator, from the theorem there are $\frac{36!}{18!\cdot 18!}$ ways to partition the $36$ cards into two sets of $18$ cards and $18$ cards.

Hence the result.